# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key itemname

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, ios7

What I am trying to do is take the text that is in my uitextfield called `editItemField` and write the value in the NSString called `toDoItemName` to my core data model with the attribute named `itemname`.

Im getting the above error. My core data model has one attribute named `itemname` I am assuming think this maybe means I am doing something with an object from an NSArray but I cant do that because its not part of the managedObjectContext?

**error**

`setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key itemname.'`

**code**

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (self.editItemField) {
    // Update existing device
    [self.toDoItemName setValue:self.editItemField.text forKey:@"itemname"];
}
    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**prepareforsegue**

Im passing the item from the uitableview through this prepareforsegue. its populating my uitextfield on the new viewcontroller. the intention is to edit the item and then update the core data model with the new value.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditItemSegue"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    Item *item = [[self fetchedResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [segue.destinationViewController setToDoItemName:[item valueForKey:@"itemname"]];

}
}
```

**edit**

Can someone tell me if this looks correct in sending the managedObjectContext?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditItemSegue"]) {
    EditItem *item = [segue destinationViewController];
    item.managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
}
}
```

**updated segue**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditItemSegue"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    Item *item = [[self fetchedResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    EditItem *destination = (EditItem *)segue.destinationViewController;
    destination.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;
    destination.toDoItem = item;
}
}
```

[NSManagedObject rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc223f5d350 2015-06-11 23:10:31.717 LittleToDoApp[95329:10363535] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[NSManagedObject rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc223f5d350

Ive never seen this error. Is this because it doesnt know where to send this to in the EditItem view? This happens of course when I tap on an item in the uitableview.

Comment: What is the type of `self.toDoItemName`?

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *editItemField; ` 
`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *toDoItemName;  `
`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;  `

Comment: So it is an `NSString` - why would you treat it as a dictionary?  You need a reference to your `NSManagedObject` instance.

Comment: This is my first foray into core data. could you help with a little more context of how that is done?  im still trying to wrap my head around all of this.

Comment: You have an object, `item` in your prepareForSegue - This is your managed Object, and it has a field `itemname`. You are passing just this field, which is a string, in prepare for segue, but you need to pass item.

Comment: Hrmmm  I think I am mixing my thoughts on how it should work. I know how it works with standard archiving and sqlite but i guess at this point i need to go back to my prepareforsegue and fix that ?

Comment: Yes, you should just send the entire item and then let your view controller extract the fields it wants to display

Comment: I added an update to my initial post. Can you let me know if that looks correct in sending the managedObjectContext to the other vc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the `NSManagedObject` instance to your next view controller, not just a single String

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditItemSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        Item *item = [[self fetchedResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NextVCClass *destination = (NextVCClass *)segues.destinationViewController;
        destination.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;
        destination.toDoItem=item; 
    }
}
```

You need to change NextVCClass to the class of your destination UIViewController subclass

Comment: updating original post

Comment: You need to change the definition of `toDoItemName` in your destination view controller class.  It needs to be an `Item *`, not an `NSString *`.  Note that in my answer I used `toDoItem`, to `toDoItemName` as this is a better name for a property that is an `Item`

Comment: Omg. Why can't I think.

Comment: I dont know if I am tired or I am just realizing how much I still dont understand, even though this seems like basic stuff.  This is changed where i declare the todoitemname property in my header? Like this: @property (nonatomic) Item *toDoItem;

Comment: Yes - the @property definition in the .h file for your destination view controller

Comment: Ahh I needed to import my item.h  That cleared up the unknown type error I was getting. Then made sure I changed it in my prepareforsegue.  Now I need to get the text field to spit out the managedobject :)

Comment: Your new error message is caused by treating your `item` property as a string - somewhere in your code you haven't accounted for the fact that you need to use `self.item[@"itemname"]` instead of just `self.item` to get the string value.

Comment: I'll look and see what I can find. I appreciate your help!!

Comment: I had some code where I was going to have a label indicate that the item had been saved. i decided against it for the time being. i commented that line out and now i can get to the EditItem vc.